# How to load in Powershell a DLL that is missing a manifest

Tags: powershell, dll

These lines:

"[Environment]::Is64BitProcess"

"[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\MvxAPI\MvxSockx64.dll")
"

gives these results:

True

Exception calling "LoadFile" with "1" argument(s): "The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131018)"
At C:\GitRepo\PowerShellScripts\ApiDllTest.ps1:11 char:1
+ [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\MvxAPI\MvxSockx64.dll")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadImageFormatException

The DLL is supplied by the ERP manufacture (Infor M3) and I'm trying to use it to send transactions to the ERP from a PowerShell program I've created.  Since I'm not a system admin but instead just a nerd that supports the ERP, I'm actually clueless as to what I'm doing related to the DLL.  Google has gotten me this far but i can't get beyond this error.  The same error returns when I attempt to use the non x64 version.

Thanks for your wisdom.  All suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Also looking for an answer to this. I need something that is similar to a LoadLibrary call that you may see in process monitor when a binary loads up.